# Factorizing Faster

Tags: factoring

As one of the steps in a calculation, I had to factorize the following quadratic polynomial:

$$12x^2 - 11x - 15$$

Using guess and check, and after roughly 10 minutes, I came to the following solution:

$$(4x + 3)(3x - 5)$$

I stumble upon factoring these kinds of quadratics all the time, and they take up a majority of the time in answering a multi-step question. Is there a method more efficient than guess and check which would help me get to the answer in less time?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: Guessing is supposed to be a shortcut if you see it quickly. Otherwise, the quadratic formula is the generic approach.

Comment: $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ always works. In this case, it would give you $x_{1,2}=-\frac34,\frac53$. Therefore, $12x^2-11x-15=(x+\frac34)(x-\frac53)$.

Comment: @barakmanos You forgot the coefficient $a$ at the beginning of your final expression.

Comment: @thanasissdr: I can't see anything that I have forgotten here.

Comment: As a note, the quadratic formula can be readily derived by _completing the square_, if you're familiar with that method. It's good to do this exercise yourself so you can understand why it works.

Comment: @barakmanos $12x^2 -11x - 15 = \mathbf {12} \cdot (x+3/4) (x-5/3)$

Comment: @thanasissdr: Oh right... but I can't edit the comment anymore at this point....

Comment: @barakmanos Don't bother! Just for the sake of correctness. :)

Comment: Multiplying the 12 does give the right answer, but why do we have to multiply it when the 12 was taken into account when solving the quadratic formula? Why aren't the two solutions we get from the quadratic enough to satisfy the equation?

Comment: @Arjun Because the formula just finds the roots. All quadratic polynomials with the same zeros (Assuming there are two) are equal, up to a multiplicative factor.

Answer (score 2):

I solve it like this 
$12x^2- 11x -15...(1)$ we will search for two numbers their product is $12(-15)$ and their sum is $-11$. I look to $12 ( -15) = 4(3) ( -5)(3)$ and I start to multiply them so I construct two numbers and check their sum. In this example it is clear that $(-20), (9)$ satisfies the conditions.

To factor $(1)$ we need to choose $a, b$ in $(ax + n)(bx + m)$ such that $ab = 12$ you may choose $3, 4$ or $2, 6$ or $1, 12$. If you choose $a=2, b=6$ . $(2x + n)(2x + m)  $ now $n , m$ are $-20 , 9$ divided by $2, 6$. Finlay 
$\displaystyle \left( 2x + \frac{-20}{6}\right) \left( 6x + \frac{9}{2}\right)$
Or 
$\displaystyle \left(2x + \frac{9}{6} \right) \left(6x + \frac{-20}{2}\right)$. 
If you chose $a$ and $b$ to be $3 ,4$ we may write it like 
$\displaystyle \left(3x + \frac{-20}{4} \right) \left(4x + \frac{9}{3} \right) $

Adding an important notice. You see in my work for example in this factoring

$\displaystyle \left(3x + \frac{-20}{4} \right)\left( 4x + \frac{9}{3}\right) $ 
I divided $9$ by $3$ since $3$ is the coefficient of $x$ in the other brackets and I divided $-20$ by $4$ since it is the coefficient of $x$ is the other brackets you can see that in all the ways I end up with.

Answer (score 0):

$$12x^2 - 11x - 15=(12x^2 - 20x)+(9x-15)=4x(3x-5)+3(3x-5)=(3x-5)(4x+3)$$

Comment: This is great, if you are lucky enough to come up with that particular way of splitting the $-11x$ term up into two pieces. But you haven't really helped OP if you can't say how you found that.

Answer (score 0):

One method you might like to try is to list the ways the first coefficient can be factorized, and the last coefficient can be factorized:
$$\binom{12}{1},\binom{6}{2},\binom{4}{3}.........\binom{15}{1},\binom{5}{3}$$

Now, after some obvious elimination of unlikely candidates, pick a pair on the left which can multiply a pair on the right (either way up) so that the **difference** is 11 (difference because of the minus sign).

In this case we can quickly spot the pair $$\binom{4}{3}...\binom{5}{3}$$ which does the trick, so you can construct the brackets accordingly as $$(4x+3)(3x-5)$$

Answer (score 0):

$Ax^2 + Bx + C$

If you're good at arithmetic, you can use this method. Find two numbers, say $m$ and $n$, such that $mn = AC$ and $m + n = B$ Write the expression as

$(Ax^2 + mx) + (nx + C)$

and it will be factorable.

For example $12x^2 - 11x - 15$

$$AC = (12)(-15) = -180$$

That means we are looking for a positive and a negative number whos product is $-180$ and whos "sum" is $-11$.

For the moment, forget about the minus sign and make a table of the factors whos product is 180.

```
   1   180
   2    90
   3    60
   4    45
   5    36
   6    30
   9    20
  we can stop here because we see that the difference
  between 9 and 20 is 11.
```

So $m$ and $n$ are $9$ and $-20$.

\begin{array}{c}
12x^2 - 11x - 15 \\
(12x^2 + 9x) + (-20x - 15) \\
3x(4x + 3) - 5(4x + 3) \\
(3x - 5)(4x + 3)
\end{array}

It looks complicated, but with practice, it goes pretty fast. And there is no guessing required.